# Is there something I can do to my screen to make it less reflective?

Tags: laptop, display

I have a HP envy 17. It's a good machine, only problem is, unless the light in the room is very low, I can see myself reflected in the monitor. If the image is very dark (especially since I like darkmode stuff), things get very hard to see in low light.

So is there any modification I can do to the computer to make the Screen less reflective? Turning the brightness all the way up doesn't help much either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An anti-glare or privacy filter will perform this duty for you. Search your favorite online store for 'screen diffuser'.